# How to figure out size and location data from a command in Datamax Programming Language (DPL)?

Tags: dpl

So, I am trying to make changes to the printed label format at one of our clients, but unfortunately, am not able to fully figure out how do the commands work with the provided arguments.

More specifically, I have a command which is `2900SA00775019201300130SKID: <S>.`

Can someone please help me explain how will the associated text be sized and placed, and what arguments/numbers in the above command are responsible for such?